# When combining two images with CIFilter(CISourceOverCompositing), lost alpha channel

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image, cifilter

I want to put an animation to an image and generate as a video, So I'm trying to merge the background image(CIImage) and one of animation frames(CIImage) with CISourceOverCompositing filter, but I found that all the transparent images (animation frames) become not transparent anymore, All the alpha values have been rounded(<0.5->0.0, >=0.5->1.0). Maybe I chose the wrong filter, But I cannot find the right one to fit my requirement. Is there any good suggestion? Thank you for your help anyway.

I wrote a sample code which is very easy:

```
- (void)generateSampleImage {
CIImage *background = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"background" withExtension:@"png"]];
CIImage *foreground = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"foreground" withExtension:@"png"]];




CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];
[filter setValue:background forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
[filter setValue:foreground forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
self.imageView.image = [self imageWithCIImage:outputImage];




NSURL *baseUrl = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                         inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *outputUrl = [baseUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"output_image.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image) writeToFile:outputUrl.path atomically:YES];
}
```

the background image to combine with:
[image: the background image to combine with]
the foreground image to combine with:
[image: the foreground image to combine with]
the output image with CISourceOverCompositing filter:
[image: the output image with CISourceOverCompositing filter]
the ideal image that I want:
[image: the ideal image that I want]

Comment: Please show us the code you're using for the compositing. I would be surprised if CoreImage didn't produce the correct resulting alpha.

Comment: Try making the background image a .jpg;

Comment: Didn't work, still lost part of alphas.